# Why "Vous ne pouvez pas mettre d'équipement" and not "Vous ne pouvez pas mettre un équipement" or "Vous ne pouvez pas mettre des équipements"?

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation

In the sentence "Vous ne pouvez pas mettre d'équipement" why is "de" used? I know that after "pas", one would use "de" rather than "des" or "un(e)", but does this rule count if there is another verb after "ne..pas"?

> Je ne mange pas de pommes

if that's correct, is

> Je ne peux pas manger de pommes

Correct as well?

Answer (score 1):

"de" est utilisé ici pour désigner quelque chose de **qualitatif**. C'est pour cela que l'on utilise pas "des" ou "un(e)" après "pas" ou "ne...pas" qui sont des articles définis, en général.

Vos deux phrases

> Je ne mange pas de pommes
>   Je ne peux pas manger de pommes

sont donc **correctes**, mais ne *signifient pas la même chose*.

La première

> Je ne mange pas de pommes

fait simplement comprendre à votre interlocuteur (la personne avec qui vous discutez) que vous ne mangez pas de pommes. Vous n'évoquez pas de raison particulière. En revanche

> Je ne peux pas manger de pommes

induit le fait que *ne pouvez pas* manger de pommes. Cela vaut aussi les autres langues.

> I don't eat apples  =/=  I can't eat apples

---

Il y a également certains exemples (rares) où vous verrez apparaître "des" après "ne...pas" ou "pas".

> Il n'y en pas des masses.

Answer (score 1):

> Vous ne pouvez pas mettre un équipement.

would be correct if you added some precision after it (especially an indication of a place). For example:

> Vous ne pouvez pas mettre un équipement *à cet endroit* / *ici*.

I can't find a sentence where we would use this one (which doesn't sound natural for me):

> Vous ne pouvez pas mettre des équipements

instead of this:

> Vous ne pouvez pas mettre d'équipement.

You could also say

> Vous ne pouvez pas mettre cet équipement.

if you are referring to a specific equipment.

---

Be careful with

> Je ne mange pas de pomme(s)

as it may be ambiguous, you can understand:

- you are not eating an apple *at the present time*
- you usually don't eat any apple

To determine the right meaning you need more information.